# Understanding the Virto Functionalities flow

Tags: virtocommerce

im new to virto Commerce i just downloaded it and ran it , so 
how can i understand how the functionality of the virto works, 
like for example the "cart" how dose it get filled up and how the platform knows about it ? 
most likely apis 
but can any one show me how it works in details or maybe a documentation for tutorial or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtoCommerce has [official site](http://virtocommerce.com) and good [docs](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide). It has no special workflow that describes how it works, but it has some diagrams & docs (even at main page) that describe platform in common words. Also, there is many topics in docs, that describe specific cases, like module development & installation. You can start with [this tutorial](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/development-scenarios/developing-a-custom-solution).

Comment: Im a developer , thou im not very experienced so how can i Understand the 
Implementation of virto  all of it , word by word i think its very rich has good practice